# ASP.NET web.api. Can I use client authentication certificates without https?

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, x509

I want to use client authentication certs in a web.api application running on IIS without https. This can be achieved with WCF but it seems it's not possible with web.api. The article below categorically states this but I wanted to understand why it cannot be done.

http://southworks.com/blog/2014/06/16/enabling-ssl-client-certificates-in-asp-net-web-api/

Note: I understand why this should never be done in production. The requirement is to run the service in a test environment where SSL is not available.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you let the application validate the certificate instead of IIS.

Make sure Client Certificates is set to 'Accept' in IIS under SSL Settings. This will ensure the certificate is passed through to the application. 'Require SSL' does not need to be ticked.

You can then implement your own certificate validation in code. For example:
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/11/client-certificate-authentication-middleware-for-katana

```
public class ClientCertificateAuthenticationHandler :
  AuthenticationHandler<ClientCertificateAuthenticationOptions>
{
    protected override Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var cert = Context.Get<X509Certificate2>(“ssl.ClientCertificate”);


        if (cert == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        try
        {
            Options.Validator.Validate(cert);
        }

        catch
        {
            return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(null);
        }

        var claims = GetClaimsFromCertificate(
          cert, cert.Issuer, Options.CreateExtendedClaimSet);

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.AuthenticationType);

        identity.AddClaims(claims);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
          identity, new AuthenticationProperties());

        return Task.FromResult<AuthenticationTicket>(ticket);
    }
}
```